# How to strip any characters inside [ ] inclusive [ ] in a string using Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

My string inputs from my input files columns are `qo_lc[m3/h]`, `TAMB[DegC]`, `mo_lc[Kg/s]` etc

Required output for respective strings are `qo_lc`, `TAMB`, `mo_lc`.

My C# code

```
for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnList.Count; columnIndex++)                                    
// Tab delimited input file columns
{
  string c_string = columnList[columnIndex]; //string input qo_lc[m3/h]
  string tmp = Regex.Replace(c_string, "[.*]", ""); //required output qo_lc
//How to proceed with Regex.Replace Syntax
  columnList[columnIndex] = tmp;

}
```

Comment: And what appears to not be working?  What error messages are you getting?

Comment: @ Dan-o i was using \\W to avoid special characters my requirement was to strip all characters after every occurrence of open [

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
string tmp = Regex.Replace(c_string, "[.*]", "");
```

to

```
string tmp = Regex.Replace(c_string, @" ?\[.*?\]", "");
```

Comment: @user3409888 I am glad to help. But you have not accepedet it as answer. )) Click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Comment: @ Farhad Jabiyev How to avoid spaces in the prefix of the same input string "     qo_lc[m3/h]" to "qo_lc" i am using                    string tmp = Regex.Replace(c_string, "\\s", "");
string finaltmp = Regex.Replace(tmp, @" ?\[.*?\]", ""); need a single Regex.Replace function instead of using two

Comment: @user3409888 if you want to avoid spaces in the prefix you can use `TrimStart()`  function.  The final statement will be : `string tmp = Regex.Replace(c_string, @" ?\[.*?\]", "").TrimStart();`